# Wifi driver compiling error

Tags: 14.04, wireless, compiling, arm, realtek-wireless

I am trying to install LM 816 driver on my ARM v7 Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I downloaded the drivers from the official website of LM. Then I extracted them and I tried to install them with the install.sh file, but the result is not successful, this is the response I got:

```
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0

#
Decompress the driver source tar ball: rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509.tar.gz rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/ rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/runwpa rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/wlan0dhcp

.......

rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509/platform/platform_ops.h rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509 Authentication requested [root] for make driver: make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build >M=/home/ubuntu/LM816_RTL8188EUS_LINUX_v4.3.24_16705.20160512/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.24_16705.20160509 modules make: * /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build: No such file or directory. Stop. make: * [modules] Error 2

#
Compile make driver error: 2 Please check error Mesg
#
```

One strange thing is that `/lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build` actually exists, so I don´t know where the problem is.

With  `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'` I don´t get anything,

With `rfkill list`:

> Can't open RFKILL control device: No such file or directory

And with `uname -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu-armhf 3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty #7 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 7 12:19:51 CET 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

With `dpkg-query -S /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty` I get:

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty
```

With `lsusb` I can see that it is connected:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

However with `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture}\n linux-image\*` I enter like in a program and I have to control C to exit.

The output of `ls -la /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build`is :

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Dec  7  2017 /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build -> /home/ander/Documentos/Kernel/linux-toradex

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster, I updated the question with the commands you asked, hope to be useful.

Comment: Thanks again @DavidFoerster, I updated the question with your  needs.

Comment: Sorry @DavidFoerster I thought that I answered  the question about the kernel. The kernel is provided by the vendor of the of the ARM machine. I dowloaded the source code, I made some changes and compiled it using make -j3 uImage command. Then I wrote the kernel and the Ubuntu image in an sd card and I reflashed the ARM machine. At this moment I can not test your last command because I am not at the office, but I will do it as soon as I could. Thanks.

Comment: Okey @DavidFoerster the last command says: dpkg-query: no packages found matching linux-image* . Thanks a lot for your work.

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen the question. However, since you're using an ancient kernel patched by a third party, it's unlikely that you're going to get a good answer here. Your system is just too different from what most people think of when they say "Ubuntu" (including Canonical).

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include the command and output of `ls -a /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build` ? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @Andermutu my apologies for the typo. what I'm actually looking for is `ls -la /lib/modules/3.1.10-gbe10973-dirty/build` (the long listing showing permissions, etc.)

Comment: @ElderGeek no problem, thank you again for effort. I have updated my question. That command shows a directory of my laptop, not from the ARM device. That diretory is where I dowloaded and compiled the kernel.